# When I run pcolor plots on Matlab the axis text appears smudged and unreadable

Tags: matlab, graphics

When I run pcolor plots (only pcolor, plot is fine) on Matlab the axis text appears smudged and unreadable. See attached figure.

[image]

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with Matlab R2012b under a VMWARE virtual machine hosted by WIN7.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the figure/axis property as follows:

- 1 Edit > Axes Properties

[image]

- 2 In the font tab, change font size etc. to make your figure more legible.

[image]

Comment: Hi David, the issue is not related to simply changing the font. Also, its on Linux not Windows, in windows I also dont have this problem.